# Run post-integration-test goals on failing build

Tags: maven, maven-3, integration-testing

I need the goals in **post-integration-test** phase to run regardless if some goals in the **pre-integration-test** or **integration-test** phase fail. Is it possible?

Comment: What's wrong with `mvn verify`? These are life-cycle-phases which will run allways. May be you can show your pom file? Or better your error messages etc. which show the cause of the problem?

Comment: The answer to your question likely depends on which plugin goals you have bound to those phases.

Answer (score 0):

You can force maven-surefire-plugin to ignore tests failure.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.16</version>
   <configuration>
        <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

The only thing is that the build will finally be marked as SUCCESS.

Maven failsafe plugin tries to avoid this problem. Check this link out:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/

Comment: surefire (for unit tests) and failsafe (for integration tests) are different plugins